# Code from example, error: Expected ";" but found "class" and more syntax errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In new to React, and I'm trying to understand examples from the Web.
Could You tell me what is wrong with that code?

```
class MyComponent extends React.component {
constructor() {
    this.state = {

        counter: 0,
        items: [1, 2]
    };
}
increase(this) {
    this.state.counter++;
}
addItem() {
    this.state.items = this.state.items.push(this.state.items.length + 1);
}
render() {
    <
    div class = ”data” >
        <
        div > {
            this.state.counter
        } < /div> <
        ul > {
            this.state.items.map(item => ( <
                li key = {
                    item
                } > element {
                    item
                } < /li>
            ))
        } <
        /ul> <
        /div> <
        div class = ”actions” >
        <
        button type = ”button” onclick = {
            this.increase
        } > zwiększ < /button> <
        button type = ”button” onclick = {
            this.addItem
        } > dodaj < /button> <
        /div>
}
```

}
ReactDOM.render( < MyComponent > , document.querySelector("body"));

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- methods must bind to class
- do not directly mutate state, use setState
- render must have a return
- must return a single outer wrap or use fragment
- class is className in react
- onclick is onClick in react
- don't inject directly into body, create a root div

Check out the working code snippet below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      items: [1, 2]
    };
  }
  //methods must bind to class
  increase = () => {
    //do not directly mutate state, use setState
    this.setState(state => ({
      counter: state.counter + 1
    }));
  };
  //methods must bind to class
  addItem = () => {
    //do not directly mutate state, use setState
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: [...state.items, state.items.length + 1]
    }));
  };
  render() {
    //render must have a return
    //must return a single outer wrap or use fragment
    //class is className in react
    //onclick is onClick in react
    return ( <
      React.Fragment >
      <
      div className = "data" >
      <
      div > {
        this.state.counter
      } < /div> <
      ul > {
        this.state.items.map(item => ( <
          li key = {
            item
          } > element {
            item
          } < /li>
        ))
      } <
      /ul> < /
      div > <
      div className = "actions" >
      <
      button type = "button"
      onClick = {
        this.increase
      } >
      zwiększ <
      /button> <
      button type = "button"
      onClick = {
        this.addItem
      } >
      dodaj <
      /button> < /
      div > <
      /React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

//don't inject directly into body, create a root div
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```